# Android app Locale language change not working for EN, but working for other languages

Tags: android

I am trying to add both `FR` and `EN` to my app, so I used the editor to translate the strings, thus creating a `strings.xml(en-rGB)` and a `strings.xml(fr-fFR)`. I am using them inside of a spinner, so when I choose `RO` (default languade) or `FR` the string from all over the app change. But when I choose `EN` it doesn't change any string. I created both `FR` and `EN` simultaneously, so I cannot seem to find any difference between them, that might make the app not behave as I like.

[image]

The code where I switch between laguages:

```
 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            TaraITEM clickedItem = (TaraITEM) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            String clickedCountryName = clickedItem.getCountryName();
            pozitie = position;
            if(!clickedCountryName.equals(lastCountryName)) {
                lastCountryName = clickedCountryName;
                if (clickedCountryName.equals("FR")){
                    setLocale("fr");
                    recreate();
                } else if (clickedCountryName.equals("EN")){
                    setLocale("en");
                    recreate();
                }else if(clickedCountryName.equals("RO")){
                    setLocale("ro");
                    recreate();
                }
            }
        }
```

And the list created, that I double-checked so there won't be any typo:

```
 private void initList() {
    mCountryList = new ArrayList<>();
    mCountryList.add(new TaraITEM("RO", R.drawable.steag_ro));
    mCountryList.add(new TaraITEM("EN", R.drawable.steag_en));
    mCountryList.add(new TaraITEM("FR", R.drawable.steag_fr));
}
```

EDIT: addes `setLocale` method:

```
 private void setLocale(String limba){
    Locale locale = new Locale(limba);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale= locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("Setare limba", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putString("Limba mea", limba);
    editor.putInt("Pozitie", pozitie);
    editor.apply();
}
```

Comment: I think that the difference is the dialect, in your case it is british english, maybe you will need to add that too... if that doesn't work, it would be great if you could add to your question the setLocale method content :)

Comment: Try to set the locale string to "en-rGB"

Comment: I picked british english as it's the most common. Maybe the `setLocale("en");` must use anything else instead of `en`? I also added the `setLocale` method. I tried with `en-rGB` and also `gb`

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to solve this issue by adding another `locale` for `RO` because `Android Studio` has `en` as  default language. So the source `strings.xml` file will be used as `en` `locale`. In my case, the default `strings.xml` had `ro` translations, so when I tried to use `en`, the app would use the `default`, so romanian translations.